# angular how to use two html file from one ts file

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two different Html view that wants to use the same ts file. is there a way to load them by a condition like a bellow

```
@Component({
  selector: "otk-specification",
  templateUrl: templateUrl: Responsive ? "./specification-responsive.component.html" : "./specification.component.html",
})
export class SpecificationComponent implements OnInit{}
```

or for example, load this ts to responsive component

Comment: Would you mind telling why you want to use same typescript file for two different templates? If you are sharing some common data by this way, you most probably need *service* file instead.

Comment: because I have two different views for mobile and desktop

Comment: With media queries or ex the bootstrap Framework you can often use the same html file for both mobile and desktop

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by extending from base ts.
make ts file for the second view that extending from first

```
@Component({
  selector: "otk-specification-responsive",
  templateUrl: "./specification-responsive.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./specification-responsive.component.scss"]
})
export class SpecificationResponsiveComponent extends SpecificationComponent{
 constructor(){
   super()
 }
}
```